# Can't run monodevelop without gksu on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, asp.net, monodevelop

My new installation of monodevelop (whatever the default ubuntu repos have) on a fresh install of 10.04 stopped working after just one test run. As I wanted to get the latest version anyway, I removed it and did an autoremove to clear out the unneeded files. Then ran system update, and then installed version 2.4. But nothing has changed. Clicking on the launcher (or doing monodevelop > enter in "run" or terminal only brings up the splash screen for a split second which disappears without a trace.

However, I just tried (for no apparent reason whatsoever) "gksu monodevelop" and it ran normally. Can someone explain why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `strace monodevelop` and look for permissions-related errors.

Comment: Although this led to my solving the problem, I really don't get why the permissions would get messed up like that. strace did show I didn't have permissions, so I just deleted the entire folder and started up monodevelop again, which merely recreated the folder with the right permissions.

Comment: Tough to tell without retracing your steps from the beginning, but I've seen similar things happen if the first time that folder is created I was running as root, maybe even as part of the installer.